# How to find count of users in all public groups

Tags: apex, public-group

I am trying to find a count of users in all public groups in a salesforce org. Has anybody done any apex class which can get the results?
Buyan

Answer (score 1):

Execute the below code. You will get the answer.

```
List<group> groupRecList = [SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName FROM Group WHERE Type = 'Regular';
Set<Id> SetOfUsers = new Set<Id>();
for (GroupMember GrpMem : [Select GroupId, UserOrGroupId From GroupMember Where GroupId IN :groupRecList]){
    if (GrpMem.UserOrGroupId.getSObjectType() == User.SObjectType)
        SetOfUsers.add(GrpMem.UserOrGroupId);
}
system.debug('SetOfUsers==>'+SetOfUsers.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the `GroupMember` [object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_groupmember.htm). But don't forget to exclude Ids that start with the same prefix as groups (because groups can be referenced in other groups too).